# Leetcode linked list detect cycle - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am looking to find a way to detect cycle in linked list using Array in PHP. Please note I am aware of two pointer approach but I am keen on understanding approach if it is feasible to achieve this with php array.

in Java code sample on leetcode is as below:

```
public boolean hasCycle(ListNode head) {
    Set<ListNode> nodesSeen = new HashSet<>();
    while (head != null) {
        if (nodesSeen.contains(head)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            nodesSeen.add(head);
        }
        head = head.next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean [double linked lists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.spldoublylinkedlist.php)?

Comment: hello, no I am not looking for using SplDoublyLinkedList class, I trying to find if it is feasible to use array to find the cycle in linked list.

Comment: Please give an example array. You can also create a lookup array as helper like nodeSeen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the given info I would rewrite it like this utilizing also an array as hashmap for visited nodes.

```
function hasCycle(SplDoublyLinkedList $list): bool
{
    $nodesSeen = [];
    $list->rewind();
    while ($current = $list->current()) {
        if (isset($nodesSeen[$current]))
          return true;
        $nodesSeen[$current] = true;
        $list->next();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Testing with having a cycle on `a`.

```
$list = new SplDoublyLinkedList();
$list->push('a');
$list->push('b');
$list->push('c');
$list->push('a');
var_dump(hasCycle($list));
```

> true

Testing with having no cycle.

```
$list = new SplDoublyLinkedList();
$list->push('a');
$list->push('b');
$list->push('c');
$list->push('d');
var_dump(hasCycle($list));
```

> false

Answer (score 0):

one more approach I have come across (no that efficient though):

```
function hasCycle($head) {
    $prev = [];
    while($head){
        if(in_array($head, $prev)) {
            return true;
        }
        $prev[] = $head;
        $head= $head->next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `in_array()` is searching for values in an array which is working fine, but slower than looking up for an index in a hash table, because of the more complex comparisons. I think you will notice it just on 100k+ entries. So this solution is absolutely fine.